# How to search for specific text in a preceding cell in google sheets and then run a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

You'll see in column C that there's a data validation set of options, and in column D a quantity (of items defined by C)...so in E I want a cost that is determined by whatever is selected in C * the value in D. You can see what I started to try in E2.

I've tried using IFS but this demands boolean values only. I'm so new to this so I don't know the most basic expectations of the code/formula (e.g. where parentheses/quotations need to be).

[Sheet that I'm working in](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19k__C0kliFDxOBpvHNz_PxG26kjbelS9I8Z5MApheIo/edit#gid=246448340)

Comment: It is not at all clear from your post what you are trying to do. Keep in mind that we cannot see what you see. We don't know what you know, including layout, ranges, data types or your end goal. So what makes perfect sense to you makes very little sense to those of us "out here." The most efficient and effective way to receive help is to share a link to your sheet (or a copy of it, or a sample sheet set up to illustrate the data and goal in a realistic way). If you choose to do this, be sure to set the link's Share permission (when you create it) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the original post and added a link to sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula in Cell E2:

```
=arrayformula(SWITCH(C2:C,iferror(D2:D/0, "Behavior Page Alignment"), 7.8*D2:D,iferror(D2:D/0, "Math/ELA Page Alignment"), 23.4*D2:D,iferror(1/0)))
```

It uses [ARRAYFORMULA()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) to apply the formula into multiple rows. [SWITCH()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690) to check the value of Column C and apply a specific case/expression. You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67241053/14606046) on how switch() and arrayformula() could work together.

### Output:

[image]

Since "Behavior Page Alignment Quality Check" is not added in your switch condition, Column E will be empty.